# JSF form not shown

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i want to implement a login page using jsf for that i wanted
to implement a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="../resources/css/basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="menutab"><a class="link" href="../index.jsp">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menutab"><a class="link" href="../jsf/list.jspx">Liste</a></li>
        <li id="menutab"><a class="link" href="../servlets/DataServlet">Daten</a></li>
        <li id="menutab"><a class="link" href="../servlets/ListMoviesServlet">Movies</a></li>
        <li id="menutab"><a class="link" href="../servlets/ListPeopleServlet">People</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br></br>
    <h2 id="title">Login</h2>

    <h:form id="j_security_check">
        <center>
            <h:messages errorClass="errorMessage" infoClass="infoMessage" warnClass="warnMessage"></h:messages>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Username : "/>
                <h:inputText id="j_username" value="#{loginBean.username}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Password : "/>
                <h:inputSecret id="j_password" value="#{loginBean.password}"/>

                <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginBean.login}" type="submit"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </center>
    </h:form>
</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The page is shown but the form defined here isnt shown. everything
after the title is just a white screen.
Why the form isnt rendered?

Comment: Do you see JSF code when looking at the result source?

Comment: Is your web.xml set up to use faces correctly?

Comment: The `center`-tag is deprecated in HTML 4 and not supported in HTML 5 and could result in unexpected behaviour, use css to center the content.

Comment: When i look at the sourcecode in my browser i get jsf code. yes.
The configuration in web.xml has to be okay because i have another jsf page rendering correctly. in this jsf i see html code as sourcecode

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it!

This is the jsf mapping in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As you see the url-pattern describes ".jspx"

So i have to call my jsf with "myjsf.jspx" instead of "myjsf.xhtml"

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>loginRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/jsf/login.jspx</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/jsf/error.jspx</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: Or even better, change your pattern to `*.xhtml`.

Comment: And get rid of the default suffix entry. This is only applicable on JSF 1.x / Facelets 1.x. Given your mixup of that entry and the usage of JSPX extension, I have the impression that you're reading the wrong resources while learning JSF2. You should be reading JSF2 resources, not JSF1 ones. So many things are done differently in JSF2 that you would only end up in confusion, learning trouble and disaster when checking JSF1 resources as well.